# How to create Nest Thermostat like scrolling effect?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

I am writing this after hundreds of references. I want to create/or [Nest Thermostat](https://store.google.com/us/product/nest_thermostat?hl=en-US) like scrolling effect. I found this solution https://jsfiddle.net/desandro/daZmA/ but its parent has fixed position. Which I can't use within the website.

```js
window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box'),
      docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  
  window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
        // normalize scroll position as percentage
    var scrolled = window.scrollY / ( docHeight - window.innerHeight ),
        transformValue = 'scale('+scrolled+')';

    box.style.WebkitTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.MozTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.OTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.transform = transformValue;
    
  }, false);
  
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: fixed;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="box"></div></div>
```

Can anybody assist me or suggest a good reference or a existing plugin to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the GSAP scrollTrigger plugin.

https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger

https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gOabMXv

https://greensock.com/st-demos/

It makes animating elements based on scroll position very easy. For example

```
gsap.timeline({ 
  scrollTrigger: {
     trigger: ".thermo",
     start: "center center",
     end: "bottom top",
     scrub: true,
     pin: true
  }
})
.from(".dial",  { y: innerWidth * 1.5 })
```

Comment: I will go through this. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @WPLearner you're welcome, please accept my answer if it's helped you